# What is the idiomatic way in Rust of assigning values of different types to a variable, depending on the compilation target OS?

Tags: rust, compiler-errors, compilation, rust-cargo, rust-tokio

I'm working on a codebase which binds to a Tokio socket and manages a TCP connection. In production, it binds to an `AF_VSOCK` using the [`tokio-vsock`](https://github.com/fsyncd/tokio-vsock) crate.

While developing locally on Mac, the `AF_VSOCK` API isn't available as there is no `hypervisor -> VM` connection — it's just being run natively using `cargo run`.

When running locally, I have been creating a standard [`tokio::net::TcpListener`](https://docs.rs/tokio/0.1.22/tokio/net/struct.TcpListener.html) struct and in production I have been creating a [`tokio_vsock::VsockListener`](https://docs.rs/tokio-vsock/0.2.2/tokio_vsock/struct.VsockListener.html). Both structs are *mostly* interchangeable and expose the same methods. The rest of the code works perfectly, regardless of which struct is being used.

So far, I have just kept both structs and simply commented out the one that isn't needed locally — this is clearly not "good practice". My code is below:

```rust
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), ()> {
    // Production AF_VSOCK listener (comment out locally)
    let mut listener = tokio_vsock::VsockListener::bind(
        &SockAddr::Vsock(
          VsockAddr::new(
            VMADDR_CID_ANY,
            LISTEN_PORT,
          )
        )
    )
    .expect("Unable to bind AF_VSOCK listener");

    // Local TCP listener (comment out in production)
    let mut listener = tokio::net::TcpListener::bind(
        std::net::SocketAddr::new(
            std::net::IpAddr::V4(
                std::net::Ipv4Addr::new(0, 0, 0, 0)
            ),
            LISTEN_PORT as u16,
        )
    )
    .await
    .expect("Unable to bind TCP listener");

    // This works regardless of which listener is used
    let mut incoming = listener.incoming();

    while let Some(socket) = incoming.next().await {
        match socket {
            Ok(mut stream) => {
                // Do something
            }
        }
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

I tried using the `cfg!()` macro with `target_os` set as the condition, but the compiler complained that the types returned by both `bind()` methods were mismatched.

**My question is:** What is the idiomatic way in Rust of assigning *different values* with *different types* to a variable, depending on the compilation target OS?

Comment: Create a trait, implement it for the two structs, then create the appropriate struct with cfg, use as a trait object. Alternative: An enum, again conditionally created. Also, please provide compilable code, ideally a link to the playground.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There multiple options. The easiest and a very common one in regards to usage in the stdlib itself is using a `#[cfg]` macro (instead of `cfg!()`. The following code snippet clarifies it's usage:

```rust
struct Linux;
impl Linux {
    fn x(&self) -> Linux {        
        println!("Linux");
        Linux
    }
}

struct Windows;
impl Windows {
    fn x(&self) -> Windows {
        println!("Windows");
        Windows
    }
}

fn main() {
    #[cfg(not(target_os = "linux"))]
    let obj = {
        let obj = Linux;
        obj
    };
    #[cfg(not(target_os = "windows"))]
    let obj = {
        let obj = Windows;
        obj
    };
    let _ = obj.x();
}
```

(see https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7088980d24c4a960c2158b091899d24d).

In your case this would be (untested):

```rust
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), ()> {
    #[cfg(target_os = "linux")]
    let mut listener = tokio_vsock::VsockListener::bind(
        &SockAddr::Vsock(
          VsockAddr::new(
            VMADDR_CID_ANY,
            LISTEN_PORT,
          )
        )
    )
    .expect("Unable to bind AF_VSOCK listener");

    #[cfg(target_os = "Mac")]
    let mut listener = tokio::net::TcpListener::bind(
        std::net::SocketAddr::new(
            std::net::IpAddr::V4(
                std::net::Ipv4Addr::new(0, 0, 0, 0)
            ),
            LISTEN_PORT as u16,
        )
    )
    .await
    .expect("Unable to bind TCP listener");
...
}
```

Check https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/conditional-compilation.html for available conditions, including feature flags, in case target_os is not applicable enough.

The major difference between `#[cfg]` and `cfg!()` is that `cfg!` does not remove code. According to it's documentation: "cfg!, unlike #[cfg], does not remove any code and only evaluates to true or false". Due to that you get a compile error while using `#[cfg]` is more akin to if-defs in C/C++ and remove the unused code, hence the compiler never sees the type mismatch.

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't aware of the distinction between `#[cfg]` and `cfg!()` and it makes much more sense after your explanation — much appreciated :)